# Hibernate generates wrong primary key

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I have a Hibernate entity.

```java
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_category_link", schema = "mariott_application")
public class AppCategory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "app_category_link_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "app_id")
    private App app;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id_who_added")
    private User userWhoAdded;

    @Column(name = "date_add")
    private ZonedDateTime dateAdded;
}
```

And I have a `@DataJpaTest` that generated such DDL. Surprisingly it produdes an unexpected primary key.

```sql
create table mariott_application.app_category_link
(
    app_category_link_id int8      not null,
    date_add             timestamp,
    app_id               bigserial not null,
    category_id          int8      not null,
    user_id_who_added    int8,
    primary key (app_id, category_id)     -- wrong
)
```

Why does Hibernate generate wrong primary key?

Comment: Is it possible you use this table name for other mappings as well? Apart from that, which version are you using?

Comment: This table name is unique. I use Hibernate `5.4.18.Final` with Spring Boot `2.3.2.RELEASE`

Comment: Can you debug into `org.hibernate.mapping.Table#setPrimaryKey` to see why this is set?

Comment: I guess I found the problem. I have `ManyToMany` relationship between `App` and `Category`. The links `AppCategory#app` and `AppCategory#category` are undirectional.  I think that's why Hibernate overrides the primary key with `(app_id, category_id)` during the second pass

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you use the table name multiple times e.g. also in a `@JoinTable`/`@CollectionTable`. Always make use of an existing entity as inverse `@OneToMany` rather than defining a `@ManyToMany` association to avoid this issue.